# How to change the Dash button icon?

Tags: unity, icons

How can I change the Ubuntu icon?  Here's a screen capture showing what I mean:

[image: Ubuntu button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu Tweak if you do not have it already. Then when you start it go to Gnome settings and on that tab you can change Ubuntu Logo. That will change only your logo and not a whole theme.[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add an English version screenshot to your answer so others can make this change?

Comment: @Mark - here you go Mark - english version of Gnome Settings tab in Ubuntu Tweak

Answer (score 1):

That icon depends on your icon-theme.

To change that, open Appearance (gnome-appearance-properties) and change your icon theme by clicking customize.